# How to evaluate generated association rules from training dataset against testing dataset in R by finding precision and recall?

Tags: java, r, machine-learning, data-mining

I'm currently working with `associative classification rules` in Data mining. I do not get how to generate confusion matrix for a set of multi-label association rules generated from `apriori` package in R. Suggest me ways to generate confusion matrix for association rules in R or some other evaluation method to evaluate the generated association rules against testing dataset and finding its `precision` and `recall`!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It truly depends on dataset and the expected outcome. Probably you should specify your usecase explicitly.

Comment: How to validate my rules obtained from training dataset against testing dataset and find its precision and recall.The dataset i've considered is stock market dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Association rules (unlike classification) are not evaluated with `confusion matrix` (since no class labels are there), instead `support`, `confidence` and `lift` measures are used to find importance of a rule in general. If you really want to use classification like measures for evaluation you refer to http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/publications/2004/mutter_et_al.pdf.

Comment: thanks much.The content is useful but whether there is any possible ways to evaluate the generated rules against testing dataset to ensure whether it predicts the class labels correctly as my rules are associative classification rules with class labels in consequent part.

Comment: if you are using  `associative classification` of the rules of the form `A1, A2, ..., An⇒ ci`,  where `ci` is a class label, then you can have a held-out dataset and use traditional `validation` methods to compute precision, recall, accuracy and confusion matrix of your rules on the held-out dataset (e.g., compute what proportion of the data-points with label `ci` in your validation dataset have `A1,A2,...An` present in them).

Comment: can you suggest me some of the validation methods available as i'm not quite familiar with it!  thanks in advance.

Comment: Just divide your dataset into two parts randomly (e.g., 70% training, 30% validation). Train your classifier on the first part to learn rules in terms of class labels and itemsets as features. Now on the other (held-out) dataset compute the performance of your rules (by computing precison, recall, F-mesaure, accuracy, AUC for ROC-curve etc.). You can repeat the process into different randomly chosen folds of data and do cross-validation.

Comment: I have reconfigured apriori algorithm for generating class association rules programatically.I haven't used any classifier for CAR generation.Now i'm currently working with R for evaluation part.In R we have a method apriori in arules package that takes dataset(training set) as input and generates association rules.As you suggested what is the method available in R to compute precision ,recall and F measure for these rules.As far i've seen i couldn't arrive in any explicit method to calculate these measures for class association rules.thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your code, how are you using apriori for associative classification?

Comment: As i have already said i am currently using apriori method of arules package in R to generate association rules.Among these rules i've filtered the rules with class labels in consequent to get class association rules.From these rules,i couldn't know how to proceed further to compute precision,recall.so i'm asking a suitable method available in R to get these measures.Suggest me the ideas even apart from R.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So as such you are not using any supervised classification technique, you are just filtering the rules and manually labeling them, which is not a classification technique. So, you need to compute your accuracy emtrics on your own.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a classification techinique (such a naive bayesian) on your training dataset and use it to predict the class labels on test dataset and compute confusion matrix (you can use caret package for that but before doing anything you need to prerprocess your data to separate out the features and class labels)